# Rejected Execution Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I get this error in the log file while thread is running, i don't know where this error occurs since the threads didn't stop and process data with no issues and only my problem that this error appears multiple times in the log file

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@419a9977
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@2522cdb9[Terminated,
>   pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks =
>   2123929]

I did some research, i found that in some places i shutdown the task, but that did not happen at all.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at the code we can't really inform you more about the problem. If you look at the exception then it clearly states that the threads have been terminated and their active count is zero. It seems even after  shutting down the executor you are trying to process more code using executors. Are you trying to add more task after the call `executor.shutdown()`

As per docs, New tasks submitted in method execute(Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated. In either case, the execute method invokes the RejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(Runnable, ThreadPoolExecutor) method of its RejectedExecutionHandler.

Look at the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the issue and the comment of @lambad saves my day. I had this piece of code:

```
ttlExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
...
...
...
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

ttlExecutorService.shutdown();
```

I removed the shutdown call and exception was no longer thrown